# How to access page controls inside [WebMethod] method?

Tags: asp.net

I am using Ajax to call some method from database 
this method takes parameters from the page
and gets some values from the DB
I want to populate the result to the page controls by accessing these controls in the web method.

Below is my code. I am using collapsible panel extender. On click event it collapses & should call verifyFunction method written in code behind.

```
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeSOP" runat="Server"      CollapseControlID="LinkButton1"
    CollapsedSize="0" Collapsed="True" CollapsedImage="~/imgages/addRow.gif"
   ExpandControlID="LinkButton1" ExpandDirection="Vertical" ExpandedImage="~/imgages/addRow.gif"
   ImageControlID="Image1" SuppressPostBack="true" TargetControlID="Panel1">
```

```
 <!-- JAVASCRIPT CONTENT -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function pageLoad(sender,args){

$find("collapsibleBehavior").add_expandComplete( expandHandler );

$find("collapsibleBehavior").add_collapseComplete( collapseHandler );

}

function expandHandler( sender  , args ){

    alert('I have expanded');
    // NewPlanBudget.aspx/verifyFunction
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "NewPlanBudget.aspx/verifyFunction",
            data: "flag=1",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d) {
                    alert("Sucess");
                }
            }
            }); 
}

function collapseHandler( sender  , args ){

alert('I have collapsed');


}
```

The code behind is

[WebMethod]

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cpeSOP.BehaviorID = "collapsibleBehavior";
    }

    public static void verifyFunction()
    {
         LinkButton1.Text = "Hello";

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot access page controls in web method but you can return the results to ajax and have to get the results

and also post your sample code, i dont know why are you calling page load in web-method,

and also the script must be

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "NewPlanBudget.aspx/verifyFunction",
        data: {flag="1"},
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d) {
                alert("Sucess");
            }
        }
        });
```

and you must get the value in web-method as

```
 public static void verifyFunction(string flag)
{

 }
```

and give name to link-button in design page itself

as

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Hello" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void Savedata() {
    if (HttpContext.Current != null) {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox1");      
    }
}
```